# Error when initializing Prisma 2 + Postgres docker on AWS

Tags: postgresql, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, prisma

I have been trying to create a container with Prisma 2, Postgres, and my backend service on AWS EC2. Even after adding the `npx prisma migrate --dev init --name --preview-feature` command to my Prisma Dockerfile, I see an error in my Postgres database service:

```
ERROR:  relation "_prisma_migrations" does not exist at character 126
STATEMENT:  SELECT "id", "checksum", "finished_at", "migration_name", "logs", "rolled_back_at", "started_at", "applied_steps_count" FROM "_prisma_migrations" ORDER BY "started_at" ASC
```

I attached my Prisma 2 `Dockerfile` and my `docker-compose.yml` file and would appreciate some help in trying to figure this out. I even tried using the `npx prism migrate deploy` command and that did not work (got some error about public.[table_name_1] not existing). My backend and prisma images are hosted on Amazon ECR. Also, since I specify POSTGRES_USER in the postgres service, I should have created a user with CREATEDB privileges so I don’t think I should have the shadow database issues highlighted in this discussion: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/4571

Prisma service Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.18-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install -g --unsafe-perm prisma
COPY ./ ./prisma
EXPOSE 5555
RUN npx prisma generate
CMD ["sh", "-c", "npx prisma migrate dev --name init --preview-feature && npx prisma studio"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=[user]
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=[password]
      - POSTGRES_DB=[db_name]
    volumes:
      - my-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  backend:
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    image: [backend image name]
  prisma:
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: prisma
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    image: [prisma image name]
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
volumes:
  my-vol:
```

I can confirm that `npx prisma migrate dev --name init --preview-feature` runs because I see the migration being applied in my Prisma service logs. When I don't include this command in my Dockerfile, I see a different error when opening up Prisma Studio or querying my backend service. This is the layout of my directory:

- ./[Backend_Service_Dockerfile]
- ./prisma/migrations
- ./prisma/[Prisma_Service Dockerfile]
- ./docker-compose.yml

Do I maybe have to link my volume to include the prisma folder? Or am I missing something here? I have been stuck on this for a couple of days so any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing the `npx prisma generate` before the migration